# How can I eliminate a "rank() over (...order by timestamp)" pattern in Hive?

Tags: performance, database-design, hive, anti-patterns

This pattern seems very inefficient:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1 a
  inner join (
    SELECT
       *
       ,rank() over (partition by orderNum order by orderUpdateTime) rnk
    ) b ...
WHERE
  b.rnk = 1
```

It also appears using row_number() in the same way.

The reason we have to do this is that as order changes come in from our billing system, we add a new record rather than updating the old one (I believe inability to update is a Hive limitation; if I'm wrong do point it out).

Is there an efficient way of avoiding this "history overload" problem?

I suspect the solution will be very context-specific, so I'm looking for general principles and architecture tips that would avoid ever having to deploy this pattern.  Or, just as good, a way to replace this pattern (as it appears all over our code).

Comment: Yes, in hive you can not update. But there are ways to do it. What we follow is, 1.  load new data into a temp table. 2.  Then create a view on temp table and original table - if its a new, existing row (based on key), get it from temp, if data is absent in new table, then get the data from old table.3.  And then insert overwrite the result from this view into final(old) table and drop temp table. Your data is updated from source to final table.

Comment: That's a good idea! How do you feel the performance is?  I expect it's quite a bit better than my current solution.

Comment: Everything depends on data. Now for temp table, we do incremental pull so its small and thus perf is satisfactory. We dont need to pull all data from osurce but only that are changed in last few days and process it.

Comment: consider using transactional table and do updates